# Laravel resources when called in usersController gives me a different path and an error

Tags: laravel, resources

I am a week old into laravel and am working on my first api.
Everything worked well till I decided to introduce `resources`. When I call the `UserResource` method I get an error that I can't understand. I have googled but haven't found an answer yet.

This is the error I get when I run on postman
`Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\Api\UserResource()`

The Resource file is in `app/Http/Resources/`

Checkout the path returned

- `App\Http\Controllers\Api\UserResource`

yet the one I add is

- `App\Http\Resources\UserResource;`

Laravel Code:

### app/Http/Controllers/Api/usersController.php

```
use App\User;
use App\Http\Resources\UserResource;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
             'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        $email = $request->email;
        $password = $request->password;

        $user = User::where('email', $email)->where('password', $password)->first();
        if($user) {
            $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('myapp')-> accessToken;
            $success['user'] = UserResource($user);
                return response()->json(['success' => $success], 200);
            }
        return response()->json(['error' => 'UnAuthorised'], 401);

    }
}
```

### app/Http/Resources/UserResource.php

```
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class UserResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
       return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'first_name' => $this->first_name,
            'other_names' => $this->other_names,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'phone_number' => $this->phone_number,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you wrote wouldn't work right now as you are comparing the **plain password** with its **hashed** version. To correcly handle Auth the Laravel way, you should use the proper `Auth` facade or `auth()` helper function as explained in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#authenticating-users).

Comment: I have done `composer dump-autoload` but error still persists

Comment: @mdexp Am comparing so since the phone number is the password. Its not hashed. And when I remove the UserResource() method am getting the user data.

Comment: Got my error finally. When calling the resource function it should be 
```$success['user'] = new UserResource($user)```
Thanks @mdexp

Comment: If that solved your issue, could you mark the answer as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `new` operator trying to instantiate the UserResource class. Without the new operator, PHP will look for a function called `UserResource` in the current namespace, therefore you get that error.